# M2070W Samsung scanner not working in 18.04 LTS. Printer works fine

Tags: drivers, 18.04, scanner, samsung

The scanner doesn't work although it's installed the same way as the printer (HP Linux driver). Printing works fine. 
How can I check what is wrong and if the scanner is supported?

Comment: Which group owns the scanner?  Is your user part of that group?  Can you scan as su?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific regarding the conclusion on why it does not work? Do you start a scanning software and nothing happens? The software hangs? What happens if you let it be for a while, say 5 minutes?

1. what do you get as output if you run `scanimage -L`? Does it find any scanners?
2. Can you ping the printer IP?
3. Have you installed the manufacturer drivers? `uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz` ?
4. In the directory `/etc/sane.d/`, you should have a file `smfp-samsung.conf`. Any hits with `ls /etc/sane.d/ | grep samsung`?

Thing is, I was just though my share of madness with the exact same printer...

It had worked fine for a very long time and suddenly I had the issue of `simple-scan` (and any other software I tried) hanging but if I wait 3-5 minutes it connects to the scanner and I can scan just fine. I could not for the life of me figure out what could be causing this. `wireshark` indicates proper communication as when using another computer on which the scanner works great btw...

when running debugging using

```
SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128 scanimage -L
```

it turns out there is a significant delay during processing of `xerox_mfp.conf`. Debugging that one with

```
SANE_DEBUG_XEROX_MFP=128 scanimage -L
```

indicated that the 3-5 min "sleep" was the time needed to get a time-out on trying to find my old printer at the old IP-address....

Commented out that line in `xerox_mfp.conf` and things went back to normal.

I ended up not adding the information for the new printer in the `xerox_mfp.conf` as the ports changed all the time (seen in `wireshark`). Least ammount of errors without an entry.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The first part where you ask for info should be a comment... You will be able to do that when you get enough rep. Keeo going.